# Is TerminateJobObject asynchronous?

Tags: winapi, process, jobs, terminate

I am in doubt and hesitate to use it because TerminateProcess is asynchronous ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and there is no mention on TerminateJobObject MSDN page that TerminateJobObject is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `TerminateJobObject` does not wait for assigned processes completion and returns immediately like `TerminateProcess`. I have not any proof and it's just an interpolation of WinAPI style.

Anyway after `TerminateJobObject` call when all assigned processes are killed the Job Object becomes signal like when assigned processes are terminated by timeout limit. The statement is based on my own experiments. I have not found something about this cases in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A lot of time passed since I run into that issue and I don't even remember if I solved it. Your answer seems reasonable, so that I am marking it as correct.